# ArrayList to Hashset to SharedPref

Tags: java, android, hash, arraylist, sharedpreferences

Hi I am getting a difficult time figuring out how to do this:
I have an ArrayList which its type is of Person, that includes some fields (firstName, lastName both Strings, birthdate Calendar) now I need to convert it to HashSet and save it (and then retrieve it) to Shared Preferences but i don't understand how.
This is what i've done:

```
ArrayList <Person> arrayPerson = new ArrayList<Person>();
Set <String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
SharedPreferences sharedpref;
final static String SHARED_PREF_FILE = "listOfPersons";
sharedpref = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


onCreate() {
    SaveData();
    // This is supposed to be shown on a TextView
    getData(myStringSet);
}

void SaveData() {
    Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("myStringSet", mySet);
    editor.commit();

}

Set<String> getData(String key) {
    return sharedpref.getStringSet(key, mySet);
}
```

Comment: Is your `Set<String>` holding the values from a single `Person` object?

Comment: Although this isn't a solution for your problem, I would suggest to use SQLite, instead of writing it to disk via SharedPreferences.

Comment: I know SQLite would be a better option, but I didn't get there yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, I see that you use String as a type for your set. In this case, I think you could come up with some kind of method that converts a Person object to a String and when adding the elements to the set, to make sure you invoke that method for parsing the Person to a String. You must be sure that the method that parses the Person to the String doesn't produce the same string for 2 different Persons. Of course, you should make a method that takes a String and creates a Person object from it. This explanation assumes that each String from the Set is a Person. Using a loop you add all the persons to the set.

```
for (Person p : arrayPerson) {
   mySet.add(p.convertToString());
}
```

If you read the Strings from the config file and wish to create an ArrayList of Persons from the set, you could use the following code, where Person.parseString() is a static method that parses a String and creates a Person object based on it.

```
    arrayPerson = new ArrayList<Person>(mySet.size());
    for (String person : mySet) {
        arrayPerson.add(Person.parseString(person));
    }
```

Comment: and how would you invoke that method to the Set? Say i override toString method in Person class, now what? Could you provide some code please? I am a complete beginner in Java/Android.

Comment: I've updated the response with the code for converting the ArrayList to the set.